# How to add an array of list as a new column to a spark dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an array of list.

```
array([1,2,3,4.....,50])
```

I want to add each element in this list as a new column to my current spark dataframe.
Something like this

```
col1|col2|new_col
-------------------
a   |aa  |1
-------------------
b   |bb  |2
-------------------
c   |cc  |3
-------------------
d   |dd  |4
-------------------
...
...
...
...
-------------------
z  |zz  |50
--------------------
```

withColumn seems to not work for something like this.

Answer (score 3):

Use `arrays_zip` function, for this first we need to convert existing data into array & then use `arrays_zip` function to combine existing and new list of data. Check below code.

```
list_data = [1,2,3,4.....,50]

df \
.select(collect_list(struct(F.col("*"))).alias("data")) \
.withColumn("list",F.array([F.lit(i) for i in list_data])) \
.select(F.explode(F.arrays_zip(F.col("data"),F.col("list"))).alias("full_data")) \ 
.select(F.col("full_data.data.*"),F.col("full_data.list").alias("col3")) \ 
.show()
```

Spark Version >= `2.4.0`

Comment: getting an error `'numpy.int64' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`

Comment: Spark version??

Comment: Spark 3.0.1
Right at the withColumn statement. Array is somehow causing the problem. 
Used an ordinary list and it's working but array of list isn't.

Comment: Ok..I have copied that from your question and pasted .. now updated solution check once

Comment: Yea I know list is working. I don't want a list. I have an array of list. I want that as a new column.
Even if I convert my array of list into a list and then use that list, It's giving out the same error.
I tried with a sample list like [1,2,3], then it's working.
Even if I am changing my array([list]) into a list using list(array) and then use that list. It's giving out the same error.

Comment: ok, can tell me what is data type of new column with value - array of list?

Comment: The new column will be integer.
Each integer from that array of list.